# Remove Multiple Classes to "Reset" Div

Tags: jquery, css

**RESOLVED IN MY OWN ANSWER BELOW:**

> ***Explanation***: `.removeClass()` does not accept commas to list multiple classes.

---

I am building a smart data grid full of cells that will identify (on blur) whether or not they were changed, and if the value went up or down.

Here's what it looks like. The grey tooltip appears when the user hovers a box that has been changed and tells them what the value was when the page first loaded.

---

[image]

---

**Problem:** When I lower the value in a cell, blur, then change it back to what it was, the cell correctly removes all indication that it was changed (no red/green border, no arrow, no tooltip).

However, when I *raise* the value in the cell, blur, then change it back to what it was, it is not getting rid of the green border. I've checked my code over and I cant see why it's not removing the "up" class.

> **EXAMPLE:** Change the top left cell from 12,000 to 11,000. Click off the cell. Notice the red border. Now change it back to 12,000. It
>   should now be reset to grey.
>
> Now change the value to 13,000. Click off the cell. Notice the green
>   border. Now change it back to 12,000. It is still green when it should
>   have reset to grey.

Can you guys give me some second sets of eyes to figure out where my issue lies? And perhaps suggest a way to condense my "cell resetting"?

**Relevant HTML ([full code available HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/Fgdec/8/)):**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="12000" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1000" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="100000" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Relevant CSS ([full code available HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/Fgdec/8/)):**

```
.up { border:1px solid #0F0 !important; }
.down { border:1px solid #F00 !important; }

.down-indicator {
    // some styles to create a downward triangle
}

.up-indicator {
    // some styles to create an upward triangle
}
```

**Relevant jQuery ([full code available HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/Fgdec/8/)):**

```
$(function() {
    var initialValues = [];

    $('input').each(function(index) {
        initialValues[index] = $(this).val();
        $(this).data('id', index);
    });


    $("input").blur(function() {
        var $t = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        var $s = parseInt(initialValues[$(this).data('id')], 10);

        // value has changed
        if($t != $s) {
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='tooltip'>" + $s + "</div>");
        }

        // value is the same as initial value
        if($t == $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up, down");
            $(this).parent().children(".tooltip").remove();
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
        }

        // value went up
        else if($t > $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up, down");
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
            $(this).addClass("up");
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='up-indicator'></div>");
        }

        // value went down
        else if($t < $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up, down");
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
            $(this).addClass("down");
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='down-indicator'></div>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue. It seems that `.removeClass()` does not use commas to delimit multiple classes.

**Old code:**

```
$(this).removeClass("up, down");
```

**FIXED CODE:**

```
$(this).removeClass("up down");
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/Fgdec/9/)